# mongoose findone passing the id of the request to the callback using q model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, q

I am using the mongoose query findone like this:

```
var findUser = function(){
     var deferred = q.defer();

     administratorModel.findOne({'username': 'aa'}, function(err, username){
          if(err) console.log(err);
          if(username){
          deferred.resolve(username);
          }else{
           deferred.reject('username' + query.username)
         }
     });

     return deffered.promise;    
}
```

The query of findone returning null if the username couldnt be found in the db,but I want to know which client the query couldnt find. but I got nothing because both err and username is null.

I want to find a way to access the filter query from the callback option, can i do that? How can I pass to the username in a way I could use it in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can store your data in variable and access it in callback?

```
var findUser = function (userToFind) {
    return q.when(administratorModel
            .findOne({'username': userToFind})
            .exec()
            .then(function (username) {
                if (!username) {
                    throw new Error('Not found ' + userToFind);
                }
            }));
}
```

Comment: But I am working asynchronly and another thread can change this variable